# Google API 401 Invalid Credentials

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) to access Analytics data. I successfully get authorization code from and change it for authorization token. But when I try to get any data from Analytics API I get **401 Invalid Credentials** error.

The code I'm using is from [PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'lib/API/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'lib/API/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("APP name");

$client->setClientId('xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('mysecret');         
$client->setRedirectUri('http://example.com');
$client->setDeveloperKey('mykey');

$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics');

$service = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
//    $client->refreshToken('refresh-token');
    print_r(json_decode($_SESSION['token']));

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: http://example.com');
    }
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $props = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties("~all");
    print "<h1>Web Properties</h1><pre>" . print_r($props, true) . "</pre>";

    $accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
    print "<h1>Accounts</h1><pre>" . print_r($accounts, true) . "</pre>";

    $segments = $service->management_segments->listManagementSegments();
    print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($segments, true) . "</pre>";

    $goals = $service->management_goals->listManagementGoals("~all", "~all", "~all");
    print "<h1>Segments</h1><pre>" . print_r($goals, true) . "</pre>";

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
?>
```

I tripplechecked my credentials. My access token looks something like this:

```
Object
(
    [access_token] => ya29.blablabla
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [expires_in] => 3600
    [refresh_token] => 1/Eblablabla
    [created] => 1413873721
)
```

When I try to get webproperties from GA account I get 401 error:

```
    Google_ServiceException Object
(
    [errors:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => global
                    [reason] => authError
                    [message] => Invalid Credentials
                    [locationType] => header
                    [location] => Authorization
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties?key=AIzaSyCDOiczVHVPiXhynaTkLkQ-Jp2Kr8kngS0: (401) Invalid Credentials
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 401
    [file:protected] => ...lib//API/io/Google_REST.php
    [line:protected] => 66
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => .../lib/API/io/Google_REST.php
                    [line] => 36
                    [function] => decodeHttpResponse
                    [class] => Google_REST
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google_HttpRequest Object
                                (
                                    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Content-Type] => application/http
                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
                                            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
                                            [Content-Length] => 
                                        )

                                    [url:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties?key=AIzaSyCDOiczVHVPiXhynaTkLkQ-Jp2Kr8kngS0
                                    [requestMethod:protected] => GET
                                    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [authorization] => Bearer ya29.xxx
                                        )

                                    [postBody:protected] => 
                                    [userAgent:protected] => APP name google-api-php-client/0.6.5
                                    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 401
                                    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [vary] => Origin
Referer
X-Origin
                                            [www-authenticate] => Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
                                            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                                            [date] => Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:00:46 GMT
                                            [expires] => Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:00:46 GMT
                                            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                                            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                                            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                            [server] => GSE
                                            [alternate-protocol] => 443:quic,p=0.01
                                            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
                                        )

                                    [responseBody:protected] => {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}
                                    [accessKey] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => .../lib/API/service/Google_ServiceResource.php
                    [line] => 186
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Google_REST
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google_HttpRequest Object
                                (
                                    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Content-Type] => application/http
                                            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
                                            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
                                            [Content-Length] => 
                                        )

                                    [url:protected] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties?key=AIzaSyCDOiczVHVPiXhynaTkLkQ-Jp2Kr8kngS0
                                    [requestMethod:protected] => GET
                                    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [authorization] => Bearer ya29.xxx
                                        )

                                    [postBody:protected] => 
                                    [userAgent:protected] => APP name google-api-php-client/0.6.5
                                    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 401
                                    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [vary] => Origin
Referer
X-Origin
                                            [www-authenticate] => Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequest", error=invalid_token
                                            [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                                            [date] => Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:00:46 GMT
                                            [expires] => Tue, 21 Oct 2014 14:00:46 GMT
                                            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
                                            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                                            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
                                            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
                                            [server] => GSE
                                            [alternate-protocol] => 443:quic,p=0.01
                                            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
                                        )

                                    [responseBody:protected] => {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"authError","message":"Invalid Credentials","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Invalid Credentials"}}
                                    [accessKey] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => .../lib/API/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php
                    [line] => 1010
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => Google_ServiceResource
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => list
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [accountId] => ~all
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => .../oatuhCallback.php
                    [line] => 46
                    [function] => listManagementWebproperties
                    [class] => Google_ManagementWebpropertiesServiceResource
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ~all
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself.

When using Google API you ALWAYS have to create Public access key which gives you developer key. That is your right developer key. I followed instructions from some forum and got wrong directions for getting my developer key.

Unfortunately this is not mentioned in Googles OAuth integration instructions.

Comment: Could you please provide access to the forum where you've learned how to do that?

Comment: Could you give more detailed instructions?